# equivalent for getLogger('name').setLevel('WARNING') in config.ini

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, cassandra

I configure logging in all modules in a project like this:

```
import logging
import logging.config
logging.config.fileConfig('../logging.ini',defaults={'name':__name__})
logging.getLogger("cassandra").setLevel("WARNING") #move this line into the logging.ini
```

Now I would like to move the last line into the following config file. What is the best way of doing this? Right now I copy/pasted this line into each module, although I have a shared config-file. :S

Configs I found give only examples for self-created loggers, but not overwriting properties of imported loggers.

**logging.ini**

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('../logs/%(name)s.log',)


[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your **logging.ini**:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,cassandra

[logger_cassandra]
level=WARNING
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler
qualname=cassandra
```

With this config you can write your modules like

```
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.ini', defaults={'name': __name__})
logging.warning("this is my logging message")
```

Note: I recommend the usage of [logging.dictConfig](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig). It appears to be more straight forward to me and offers a many options for your configuration. You maybe want to checkout [this example dict config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507825/python-complete-example-of-dict-for-logging-config-dictconfig) or even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45465510/using-logging-with-coloredlogs/49400680#49400680) with colored console logging.

Comment: I tried this and get: NoOptionError: No option 'qualname' in section: 'logger_cassandra'

Comment: I want to do this, because I want a central place to configure logging for my project. There is roughly 15 modules and it is cumbersome to configure logging for all of them.

Comment: Can you explain why I need to add qualname and handlers? ideally this is inherited from root. If I configure my logger with python code, I do not need to specify these.

Comment: _Can you explain why I need to add qualname and handlers?_ – this seems to be a shortcomming of `fileConfig()` method removed in newer `dictConfig()`. From [Vinay Sajip's answer](https://python-list.python.narkive.com/rQQ4PX8a/logging-oddity-handlers-mandatory-in-every-single-logger#post9) – _Particularly as I've just received the good news from Guido van Rossum
that PEP 391 (Dictionary-Based Configuration For Logging) has been
accepted, and my aim is to get it into Python 2.7 and Python 3.2._